# Does Jacoco include SpringJUnitClassRunner test coverage?

Tags: spring, jenkins, junit, sonarqube, jacoco

I have a Test.java class annotated with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` (from `spring-test-3.2.18-RELEASE.jar`). I'm finding that it does not show up in Jenkins' Jacoco Coverage Report (or on SonarQube which pulls from Jacoco reports).

## Screenshots

Sorry I've had to obfuscate company-secret info, but it's the same class under test I'm showing the coverage data for.

### Basic Coverage Report in Jenkins

[image: (screenshots being uploaded shortly)]

### Jacoco Coverage Report in Jenkins

[image]

### Further info

- I'm not sure if this is confirmation or not: http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/Sonar-4-0-Jacoco-Code-coverage-Vs-Unit-tests-coverage-SPRING-td5022529.html
  This

Comment: share the build logs to find the jacoco logs and its execution

Comment: Here it is: https://pastebin.com/TYTgZN7q . I hope my attempts to redact haven't erased key information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does work in SpringJUnitClassRunner.

After trying out the same code on my local machine with Java 8 (instead of Java 7) and a (probably) simpler execution scope, and with the following version:

```
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.6.201602180812"
```

I found that the class that wasn't getting executed on Jenkins does work. So there must be something about the Jenkins environment that is different.

Comment: The actual reason the tests weren't getting run was that gradles Jacoco plugin seems to have a bug when multiple threads are running. I needed to set the "forkAfter" (?) number to a very high number so that ask tests were executed in a single thread.